jQuery.Deferred exception: Unable to process binding "click: function(){return someFunction }" in magento2.4.7
jQuery.Deferred exception: Unable to process binding "click: function(){return someFunction }" in magento2.4.7

specify the issue in details, which page above error comes and click on what?

Please [edit] your question and properly format it rather than adding a comment.

You need to Added someFunction() with code into respective JS file.
Because currently you just added code into HTML but forgot to added someFunction() with code into JS File.

please check .I have edited my comment above
